# JS смена цвета чекбокса при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, checkbox

Очень прошу помочь. Нужно сделать для детей мини-тест, в рамках которого:
1. По нажатию на чекбокс(итемы теста) можно менять цвет данного итема (3мя кнопками, расположенными ниже).
2. После выбора цвета чекбокс должен вернуться в исходное положение но остаться с цветом.введите сюда код

```js
function checkColor(checkbox) {
  const block = checkbox.parentNode;
  const color = block.querySelector(".color");
  const gbutton = document.querySelector(".green-button");
  const rbutton = document.querySelector(".red-button");
  const bbutton = document.querySelector(".brown-button");

  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    gbutton.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      color.classList.remove("red", "brown");
      color.classList.toggle("green");
      checkbox.checked = false;
      return;
    });

    rbutton.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      color.classList.remove("green", "brown");
      color.classList.toggle("red");
      checkbox.checked = false;
      return;
    });

    bbutton.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
      color.classList.remove("red", "green");
      color.classList.toggle("brown");
      checkbox.checked = false;
      return;
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: green
  }
  100% {
    background: brown;
  }
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: brown;
  }
}

.page-content {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main__rule {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.green__rule {
  color: green;
}

.red__rule {
  color: red;
}

.brown__rule {
  color: brown;
}

.item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-wrapper input {
  display: none;
}

.item-wrapper input:checked+label {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}

.item-wrapper label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 144px;
  height: 38px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  border: 1px solid rgb(244, 244, 244);
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  color: black;
}

.item-wrapper label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.end {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.done {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Применяем знания</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="main__title">Проверьте свои знания</div>
    <div class="main__rule">
      <div>Подчеркни</div>
      <div class="green__rule">зеленым цветом луговых производителей</div>
      <div class="red__rule">красным – потребителей</div>
      <div class="brown__rule">коричневым - разрушителей</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper data-language-item">
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-1">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-1">Стрекоза</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-2">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-2">Василёк</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-3">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-3">Трясогузка</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-4">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-4">Дождевой червь</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-5">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-5">Злак</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-6">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-6">Жужелица</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-7">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-7">Мышь-малютка</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-8">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-8">Почвенный клещ</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-9">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-9">Клевер</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-10">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-10">Бабочка</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-11">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-11">Ласка</label>
      </div>
      <div class="js-item-checkbox">
        <input onclick="checkColor(this)" type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" id="item-checkbox-12">
        <label class="color" for="item-checkbox-12">Микробы</label>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="red-button">Красный</button>
        <button class="green-button">Зеленый</button>
        <button class="brown-button">Коричневый</button>
      </div>
      <div class="end">
        <button class="done">Закончить</button>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На каждый вызов `checkColor` при выбранном чекбоксе происходит добавление кнопкам  `.red-button`, `.green-button` и `.brown-button` новых обработчиков `click` с захваченными в замыкание локальными переменными. Эти обработчики накапливаются, и выполняются все при нажатии на любую из кнопок.

Такое можно сделать проще (обратите внимание на изменения в разметке):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".buttons").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList && e.target.classList.contains("color-button")) {
      var colorClass = e.target.dataset.colorclass;
      var allChecked = document.querySelectorAll(".js-item-checkbox .item-checkbox:checked");
      allChecked.forEach(item => {
        item.parentNode.classList.remove("red", "green", "brown");
        item.parentNode.classList.add(colorClass);
        item.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: green
  }
  100% {
    background: brown;
  }
}

@keyframes rainbow {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: brown;
  }
}

.page-content {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main__rule {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.green__rule {
  color: green;
}

.red__rule {
  color: red;
}

.brown__rule {
  color: brown;
}

.item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-wrapper input {
  display: none;
}

.item-wrapper .color input:checked+span {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}

.item-wrapper label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 144px;
  height: 38px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  border: 1px solid rgb(244, 244, 244);
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  color: black;
}

.item-wrapper label:hover {
  background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.end {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.done {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="main__title">Проверьте свои знания</div>
  <div class="main__rule">
    <div>Подчеркни</div>
    <div class="green__rule">зеленым цветом луговых производителей</div>
    <div class="red__rule">красным – потребителей</div>
    <div class="brown__rule">коричневым - разрушителей</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-wrapper data-language-item">
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Стрекоза</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Василёк</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Трясогузка</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Дождевой червь</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Злак</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Жужелица</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Мышь-малютка</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Почвенный клещ</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Клевер</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Бабочка</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Ласка</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="js-item-checkbox">
      <label class="color">
          <input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox">
          <span>Микробы</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="color-button" data-colorclass="red">Красный</button>
      <button class="color-button" data-colorclass="green">Зеленый</button>
      <button class="color-button" data-colorclass="brown">Коричневый</button>
    </div>
    <div class="end">
      <button class="done">Закончить</button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не подскажите, когда добавляю себе в проект, выдает: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at index.html:9

Comment: @ArtBad Пожалуйста. Надо скрипт из ответа завернуть в `window.onload` или перенести в конец страницы - перед `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная color попадает в замыкание в функциях обработки события click и поэтому накапливает в себе кучу объектов, поэтому нужно просто её каждый раз опустошать.

```
let color = block.querySelector(".color");

gbutton.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  color.classList.remove("red", "brown");
  color.classList.toggle("green");
  checkbox.checked = false;
  //просто опустоши переменную в каждой функции обработки события.
  color='';
  return;
});
```

если помог прими ответ как правильный.

Comment: Добавил, теперь консоль говорит следующее:
"Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: let color = block.querySelector(".color"); поменяй const на let